# Ag-Grid Comparator Function With Pivot And RowGroups Issue Same valueA and valueB

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm building a React webapp that uses the ag-grid library. I'm trying to use the column.comparator function to compare the top-level values of rows that are groups as rowGroup (the grid has pivot mode turned on). The comparator function's first two arguments are valueA and valueB, but I console.log the values inside of the function and they are always the same value all the way down! Has anyone else experienced this bug? Am I doing something wrong? I'm trying to add in a custom sorting for my grouped rows column, but it seems that I can't do this with the comparator function not working properly.